# Why are many cpx files created when running a Minizinc model with CPLEX?

Tags: cplex, minizinc

I ran a Minizinc model with the CPLEX solver. A folder named "cpxa67564" was created. It has many files named "cpxXXXX" (where XXXX are numbers).

What are these files? Subproducts of the compilation/execution? Is there any problem if I delete them? Why are they so many? I only ran the model a few times, yet those files are over 2K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These folders contain "node files". See [Use node files for storage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/mip/troubleshoot/61_mem_gone.html?view=kc#User_manual.uss_solveMIP.647315__User_manual.uss_solveMIP.647357) in the documentation. These are created when the [node storage file switch](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/NodeFileInd.html) is set to a value of 2 or 3. Under normal circumstances, CPLEX will remove these files and their temporary directory, but they will remain when the program terminates abnormally.